# How can I use ifelse() to merge variables in R?I've tried many times

Tags: r

I'm working on a sample of crime data, I tried to merge similar crime types because there are too many types in the column named "Primary.Type".

[image]

```
dd$Primary.Type.new <- ifelse(dd$Primary.Type.new %in% c("SEX OFFENSE", "PROSTITUTION", "OBSCENITY", " CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT"),"SEX_CRIME",dd$Primary.Type.new)
dd$Primary.Type.new <- ifelse(dd$Primary.Type.new %in% c("DECEPTIVE PRACTICE"),
                  "DECEPTIVE PRACTICE",dd$Primary.Type.new)
```

Then it turned to numbers:

[image]

Can someone tell me what to do, I've tried thousands of times.....Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't post your data or code as images. It's not searchable or copy/pasteable and it's slow to load.

Comment: Hi! Your question is not really clear, perhaps you can elaborate more on what you are looking for, what the expected result is and what you have tried? Also, try posting data in another format, not images, as @DeNovo said.

Comment: Your column is probably a `factor` rebelling against new levels. Convert it to `character` first: `dd$Primary.Type.new = as.character(dd$Primary.Type.new)`.

Comment: Got it.This is my first time using this website,still exploring.Thanks for the advice.@De Novo @Luis

Comment: @Gregor  Problem Solved:) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your variable is a factor. Let's look at a more simple example:

```
x = sample(letters, 1000, replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame(x=x)
table(df$x)

 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v 
47 45 45 34 37 37 38 43 33 34 38 35 30 41 41 43 32 39 41 47 37 44 
 w  x  y  z 
30 37 35 37
```

This comes out as we expect. But what if we try to add new values using `ifelse`?

```
df$x = ifelse(df$x %in% letters[1:13], toupper(df$x), df$x)
table(df$x)

14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I 
41 41 43 32 39 41 47 37 44 30 37 35 37 47 45 45 34 37 37 38 43 33 
 J  K  L  M 
34 38 35 30
```

The values that we coded ourselves `toupper(df$x)` are in string format, but the other values that were returned as is are numeric, which is what we don't want.

To fix this, add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your code where you read in your data.

```
df = data.frame(x=x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table(df$x)

 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v 
47 45 45 34 37 37 38 43 33 34 38 35 30 41 41 43 32 39 41 47 37 44 
 w  x  y  z 
30 37 35 37 

df$x = ifelse(df$x %in% letters[1:13], toupper(df$x), df$x)
table(df$x)

 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v 
47 45 45 34 37 37 38 43 33 34 38 35 30 41 41 43 32 39 41 47 37 44 
 w  x  y  z 
30 37 35 37
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very helpful. I'm still trying to figure out how to use this website, but I just accepted your answer.Have a good day.@brittenb

Comment: @Cecilia The key things you'll want to provide when asking a question is what's called a minimal, reproducible example. The code I used in this answer is an example of that. Since we don't have the data that you have, we need something that allows us to reproduce your error. In order to provide this, you could have used `dput(head(dd, n=20))` and pasted the output of that into your question. Second, you'll want to show what you've tried, which you did in this question. Lastly, you'll want to show your expected output so people know what answer you need. Hope that helps!